# Issue with mobX package, package is installed but cannot be resolved

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In my lately created react project I want to use mobX. I have installed mobX packages

```
"mobx-react": "^9.0.1",
"mobx-react-lite": "^4.0.5",
```

This is part of the errors I'm getting
[image]

But You can see here that package exist

[image]

Can You please suggest how to fix this error ?
I have deleted few times node_modules and installed it again, but nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install package `mobx` first, according to the [wiki page](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html) then you either choose to use `mobx-react` or a lighter version of it which is `mobx-react-lite`